# Initializing subset of variables in MonitoredTrainingSession

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I am using `MonitoredTrainingSession` in my training code and I want to initialize subset of weights from a checkpoint and the rest of the unassigned variables initialized to random values. I know how to do this using `tf.session` and initialize all the variables first and then read the variables from checkpoint using `tf.saver`.

However, I don't know how to do it with `MonitoredTrainingSession`. `MonitoredTrainingSession` has bunch of advantages for me that I don't like to give up on it and switch to `tf.Session` if there's a way to make it work with `MonitoredTrainingSession`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import copy
m_bak = copy.deepcopy(MonitoredTrainingSession)
```